# std::condition_variable::notify_all() - I need an example

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I need an example of using notify_all() method. Because I cannot understand how should it work.

Every waiting thread begins with code like that:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
condition_variable.wait(lock, [](){return SOMETHING;});
```

At the very beginning, waiting thread needs to acquire a mutex. So if there are more than one waiting thread, rest of them will wait to lock a mutex. So what is the purpose of using notify_all() if waiting threads stuck at locking mutex and do not execute a method wait() at all? These threads will wake up one by one instead of simultaneously.

Comment: Let me direct you to a great reference/example site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: It does not solve my problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mutex guards the internal state of the `condition_variable`. Calling `wait` on the `condition_variable` causes the mutex to be unlocked. So while waiting, threads do not own the mutex.

When the `wait` completes, the mutex is again (atomically) acquired before the call to `wait` returns.

The threads are not contending on the mutex, they are contending on the condition itself.

You are free to unlock the lock as soon as you return from wait if you wish. If you want to allow multiple threads to synchronise on a condition, for example, this is how you would do it. You can also use this feature to implement a semaphore.

example:

This code processes things in batches of 10. Note that `notify_all()` goes *after* the `unlock()`:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

void emit(std::string const& s)
{
    static std::mutex m;
    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
int running_count = 0;

void do_something(int i)
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
    // mutex is now locked

    cv.wait(lock,   // until the cv is notified, the mutex is unlocked 
            [] 
            {
                // mutex has been locked here 
                return running_count < 10; 
                // if this returns false, mutex will be unlocked again, but code waits inside wait() for a notify()
            });
    // mutex is locked here
    ++running_count;
    lock.unlock();
    // we are doing work after unlocking the mutex so others can also
    // work when notified
    emit("running " + std::to_string(i));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    // manipulating the condition, we must lock
    lock.lock();
    --running_count;
    lock.unlock();
    // notify once we have unlocked - this is important to avoid a pessimisation.
    cv.notify_all();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> ts;
    for (int i  = 0 ; i < 200 ; ++i)
    {
        ts.emplace_back([i] { do_something(i); });
    }

    for (auto& t : ts) {
        if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that wait() method unlocks mutex?

Comment: @AkasataAkasata wait simultaneously unlocks the mutex and enters a wait state on the condition variable. when the condition variable is notified, all waiters re-acquire the lock in order to test the condition. I'll annotate the code.

Comment: So if they are re-acquiring the lock in order, notify_all() wakes them in order too, right?

Comment: @AkasataAkasata I don't think the order of unlocking is guaranteed by the standard. 
Some docs here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

Comment: @AkasataAkasata in fact if you run the program above you'll see that the messages are printed in "random" order.

Comment: I mean that eventually notify_all() does not wake waiting threads simultaneously. They are still running one by one.

Comment: @AkasataAkasata it wakes all waiting threads simultaneously. how many actually run concurrently will depend on how many cores you have. My code serialises output to cout with another mutex, otherwise you get garbage being printed.

Comment: @RichardHodges, Only one thread can hold the `lock` at any given time, and it is not possible for `cv.wait()` to return until the thread holds the lock.  So, yeah, it _wakes_ them all simultaneously, but "wake" only means that the threads are moved from the condition variable's queue to the mutex queue.  They won't all get the lock and return from `wait()` at the same time.

Comment: @jameslarge agreed. I think we need longer than a few lines to explain it in detail. Better if Akasata does some background reading I think.

Comment: I think that everything is clear to me right now. But is it true that when notify_all() is used, every waiting thread will try to lock a mutex?

Comment: @AkasataAkasata yes. and sometimes more often than that. It is permissible to have "spurious wakeups" (see docs). This is why we must actually test a condition, and not rely only on the `notify_all()`

Comment: So I get it now. Thank you so much. Now I can't wait for std::shared_mutex, because it can make std::condition_variable even more efficient. :)